# I am having error during running fabcar sample with npm

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am getting this error when I am trying to run hyperledger-fabric sample "fabcar".

I'm following the official documentation for that but having error when I execute npm install command, it gives:

> npm WARN fabcar@1.0.0 No repository field.

Answer (score 1):

The warning message is harmless.  You should still be able to proceed running the sample.

Comment: thank you for answering. i want to know that ,is there any release of hyperledger fabric is stable in which i can work properly. because when i get to do something i find new release like now there is 1.3 rc something.. so which is the best release in which i can start working?

Comment: I think that error might be in all versions .... right now 1.2 is the current version although 1.3 official release will be out very soon so probably best to stick with that